# Prior to the insertion of Section 10(A1) to the Criminal Law Act 1977, was it a crime to obstruct the enforcement of a high court writ of possession?

Tags: england-and-wales, eviction, enforcement

Prior to the [insertion](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1977/45/section/10#commentary-key-9ca67b4657b3b65d3c4731b4920a00b9) of section 10(A1), what was the legal status of obstructing a high court enforcement officer who was on official business in the course of evicting a former tenant against whom possession had been awarded to their landlord?

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, but …

The [Courts Act 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courts_Act_2003) created the position of the [High Court Enforcement Officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Court_enforcement_officer) who answer to the [Lord High Chancellor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Chancellor).

The role had previously been carried out by sheriffs answerable to the [High Sheriff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_sheriff) of each shrieval county. Obstructing these people was a common law crime.